# gnome-terminal (or VTE) sets $TERM to xterm rather than xterm-256color

Tags: emacs, terminal, gnome-terminal, vte

Is there a compelling reason why `gnome-terminal` (and, under the hood, maybe the `VTE` widget) sets `$TERM` to `xterm` rather than `xterm-256color`?  Clearly it supports 256 colors.

For a while, I had a line in my `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` to simply `export TERM=xterm-256color`, because that's usually the terminal emulator that I'm using.  But then I open up `tmux`, and the behavior / colors are wrong in many CLI applications, such as `emacs` and `htop`, because `tmux` will set the `TERM` variable to screen-256color, *then* the shell loads and executes my `.*rc` file, which then sets the `TERM` incorrectly.

For now, I have:

```
if [ "$TERM" != "screen-256color" ]; then
    export TERM="xterm-256color"
fi
```

I don't like this, because what if one day I break out my actual VT-220 or use a different terminal emulator?

Comment: I don't understand: you say "..my .*rc file, which then sets the TERM..", but that sounds like an error: the .rc file shouldn't set $TERM, in general.

Comment: I know that it shouldn't need to, but doesn't gnome-terminal set it incorrectly?  So where else am I supposed to put it?

Answer (score 1):

For a long time, people used to look at `$COLORTERM`, and if that was set (along with `TERM=xterm`) they switched it to `TERM=xterm-256colors` instead.

Later, gnome-terminal (actually vte) removed setting `$COLORTERM`, but introduced `$VTE_VERSION`.

The newest version (gnome-terminal 3.16, vte 0.40) sets `TERM=xterm-256color` right away (which is again not quite correct, because it supports 16M colors, but there's no way to denote it in terminfo.)