# How do you change terminal settings on Fedora 20 with no termcap file only terminfo

Tags: linux, terminfo, termcap

set and tset do not change terminal type from xterm-256 color to linux
any ideas/

Answer (score 0):

Terminal type is normally set with an environment variable: `TERM`.  Applications use ncurses to lookup the terminal description using `TERM` in the terminfo database.

Most Fedora users are using `bash` for their shell.  You could just

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

on the command-line.  How to configure that for future use depends on the terminal you are using.

Further reading:

- [gnome-terminal (or VTE) sets $TERM to xterm rather than xterm-256color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965325/gnome-terminal-or-vte-sets-term-to-xterm-rather-than-xterm-256color)
- [What is the difference between xterm-color & xterm-256color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003136/what-is-the-difference-between-xterm-color-xterm-256color)